# Will Drupal robots.txt disallow still be recorded in apache log file?

Tags: apache, drupal, robots.txt

I set up some rules in robots.txt for a specific agent for my Drupal website.

I have one question. When this agent is trying to access the website, will this access still be logged in my apache access_log file?

Answer (score 1):

`Disallow` in robots.txt is not technically preventing user agents from accessing your website. Each user agent decides whether it wants to honour your robots.txt or not.

By default, Drupal is not doing anything with the content of your robots.txt file, and the robots.txt content doesn’t affect your server’s logs at all.